# How can I mute my youtube videos when hidden

Tags: javascript

how can I get my youtube videos to mute when hidden? I have some code below that works, but it is muted whether the video is hidden or not. I have tried pausing the videos, stopping the videos, etc... but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 window.my_mute = false;

$('#my_mute_button').bind('click', function(){

  $('audio,video').each(function(){

      if (!my_mute ) {

        if( !$(this).paused ) {
            $(this).data('muted',true); //Store elements muted by the button.
            $(this).pause(); // or .muted=true to keep playing muted
        }

    } else {

        if( $(this).data('muted') ) {
            $(this).data('muted',false);
            $(this).play(); // or .muted=false
        }

     }
   });

   my_mute = !my_mute;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to do it is to use the Youtube API to load your videos.

Then you can easily control when to mute then or not.

=]

Comment: I've been trying that and it doesn't seem to work. I can't figure out why. Getting frustrated with it ;)

Comment: Put the code on JSFiddle. Certainly we gonna be able to help you.